# Filter by partition in Snowflake

Tags: sql, where-clause, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

I want to filter out records where there is a record with a `start_time` before than `start_time` of **created** `status` for each `id`.

e.g. below id A has 'failed' status before 'created' based on `start_time`. So it needs to be filtered.
Whereas id B has first 'created', then another status which is acceptable.

[image]

So the expected result is only this, but I'm looking for a scalable solution that works for thousands of rows.

[image]

```
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT 'A' AS id, 'failed' AS status, '2021-05-18 18:30:00'::timestamp AS start_time UNION ALL
SELECT 'A' AS id, 'created' AS status, '2021-05-24 11:30:00'::timestamp AS start_time UNION ALL
SELECT 'A' AS id, 'created' AS status, '2021-05-24 12:00:00'::timestamp AS start_time UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' AS id, 'created' AS status, '2021-05-19 18:30:00'::timestamp AS start_time UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' AS id, 'successful' AS status, '2021-05-20 11:30:00'::timestamp AS start_time
    )
SELECT *
FROM t1
```

Comment: "*I want to filter id A and only get id B*" That doesn't make much sense. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Rajat Edited the question. Please let me know if still not clear.

Comment: The rule of thumb is that it must not be any id with a status before created

Comment: Every id has a 'created' status which is the first status needs to be recorded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this but here is an approach using `first_value`.

```
with t1 (id, status, start_time) as 
(select 'a', 'failed', '2021-05-18 18:30:00'::timestamp union all
 select 'a', 'created', '2021-05-24 11:30:00'::timestamp union all
 select 'a', 'created', '2021-05-24 12:00:00'::timestamp union all
 select 'b', 'created', '2021-05-19 18:30:00'::timestamp union all
 select 'b', 'successful', '2021-05-20 11:30:00'::timestamp)

select *
from t1
qualify first_value(status) over (partition by id order by start_time asc) = 'created'
```

All you're doing is making sure that the first status for any given id is "*created*". Think of `qualify` clause as `having` clause for `window functions`. You can also break this down into a subquery if you find that more readable.

**Note:** Solution above will also keep records that have only "*created*" status. If you want to make sure there are least two different statuses per id, modify it to

```
select *
from t1
qualify first_value(status) over (partition by id order by start_time asc) = 'created'
        and 
        count(distinct status) over (partition by id) > 1;
```